# Prism. Работа с регионами

Tags: wpf, prism

Здравствуйте. Изучая wpf, узнал, что есть prism.
Сейчас пытаюсь понять как работать с регионами. С тем как добавить единичный модуль в регион я понял. А как сделать так чтобы в один регион можно было добавить несколько модулей? Точнее
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Модуль 1,2,3,4,5 это заголовочная часть модуля(картинка может с надписью), они находятся в регионе 1. А в Регионе 2 отображается основной контент модуля.

Comment: Нашел для себя такое решение(на данный момент). 
Создал дополнительный интерфейс, который и экспортирую IViewer.
В него входят те элементы, которые нужны для формирования данных в shell. и затем просто в заголовочную часть подставляю нужный данные, а в регион 2 подставляю UserControl.
Не самый на мой взгляд приятный способ, но он работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, у вас с терминологией проблемы:
Не модули загружаются в регионы, а view. 
Модуль содержит view.

Если вам хочется добавить несколько view в один регион, вы можете использовать метод IRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(..) для регистрации вьюх в регионе.

Для того, чтобы отобразить в первом регионе данные из модуля - вам надо зарегистрировать view для него. 
Тоже самое и для второго региона.

Comment: да проблемы с терминологией возможны, так как только начал разбираться с Prism. А можно небольшой пример?

Comment: прочитайте цикл статей http://habrahabr.ru/post/176851/ и всё станет понятно.
Если будут новые вопросы, задавайте новые вопросы. В этом не стоит.