# Prism навигация

Tags: wpf, prism

Задавал вопрос про навигацию в Prism [Prism. Работа с регионами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470803/prism-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8/472741#472741). Получил ответ прочитать список статей. С навигацией разобрался.

Но появился другой вопрос. У меня приложении имеет окно с настройками, которое изначально не открыто. И получается, если я добавляю регионы в главном окне, то они отображаются нормально (навигация работает правильно), а если создать эти же регионы в другом окне(не главном), то Prism не видит эти регионы.

Shell

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="HeadersStreamSite"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentStreamSite"/>
</Grid>
```

Option Shell

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="HeadersStreamSite"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="ContentStreamSite"/>
</Grid>
```

Из примера видно, что код абсолютно одинаковый, но в первом случае навигация работает, а во втором выдает ошибку, что регион ContentStreamSite не существует.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы все же весь цикл статей по **Prism** то [прочитали](https://habrahabr.ru/post/176895/)

> ...Корневой элемент составного приложения называется оболочкой (Shell). Оболочка работает как мастер-страница для приложения и состоит из нескольких регионов (Region)...

Т.е. у вас не может быть два **Shell**. Для окна с настройками сделайте отдельное **View** которое будете загружать в основной регион по нажатию кнопочки (`RegionManager.RequestNavigate()`), или в модальном окне отображать(используя `InteractionRequestTrigger`)